# Stop Action on Navigating event of WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, action, webbrowser-control

I have created a little Win Form App in C# and added the WebBrowser component to it. What i am trying to achieve is a little app that can load a local html page from a file which has "custom" protocols in it and can of course also navigate to a web address.

For example i would have entry as follows in my webpage

`'<a href="Special://905">Close&nbsp;Company</a></TD></TR>'` which would open a task in a program.

The way i tried to achieve this was via the Navigating event as shown below

```
       private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
       {
        if ((webBrowser.StatusText.Contains("Special")))
         {
            //For some reason the stop doesn't do much it still tries to proceed to special:123
            //diplaying can not load page..
            webBrowser.Stop();

            //Launch program here.
            MessageBox.Show("Special Command Found");
         }
       }
```

Problem is that it still navigates and says it can't find of course the page.
I swapped Stop with GoBack which for some reason has the same issue the first time i run it and when i then select backward in the browser it works from thereon.

I also tried navigated and use of GoBack, besides having a flashing in the app from going back the event does not fire again after the first time anymore.

Has anyone any ideas how to solve this or what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using WebBrowser.Stop();
just set e.cancel = true;